# Is it possible to apply 'fontWeight' for Icons while using react-native-vector-icons package?

Tags: react-native

Style object is allowed to style icons.

```
<Icon name='angle-right' style={{fontSize: 22, fontColor: 'white', fontWeight: '900'}} />
```

fontSize and fontColor are working as expected, But fontWeight is not working.

Is it natural that fontWeight is not working and is there any way to make it work?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No You can't, icons don't have font weights